# What property allows this: $$(|Φ^+⟩⟨Φ^+|+|Φ^-⟩⟨Φ^-|+|ψ^+⟩⟨ψ^+|)^† =(|Φ^+⟩⟨Φ^+|)^†+(|Φ^-⟩⟨Φ^-|)^†+(|ψ^+⟩⟨ψ^+|)^†$$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that a Partial Bell basis measurement defined as
$$P ̂_0=|Φ^+ ⟩⟨Φ^+ |+|Φ^- ⟩⟨Φ^- |+|ψ^+ ⟩⟨ψ^+ |$$      $$P ̂_1=|ψ^- ⟩⟨ψ^- |$$
forms a projective measurement.

In the part where i tried to prove $P_0$ is Hermitian:     $P ̂_0^†=P ̂_0$.

I have the following step in the sample answer:

$$(Φ^+⟩⟨Φ^+|+|Φ^-⟩⟨Φ^-|+|ψ^+⟩⟨ψ^+|)^† =(|Φ^+⟩⟨Φ^+|)^†+(|Φ^-⟩⟨Φ^-|)^†+(|ψ^+⟩⟨ψ^+|)^†$$

What is the property that allows this ?

Comment: The Hermitian conjugation operation is skew-linear, and that is why it can be decomposed over a sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the property that allows this ?

Linearity of complex conjugation and linearity of transposition.

For any operators $A$, $B$, let the operator $C$ equal:
$$
C = A + B
$$
we have
$$
C^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger
$$

---

If you want to prove it in terms of complex numbers, let the set of orthonormal
$$
|v_i\rangle
$$
be a basis in the space.

The equation
$$
C=A+B
$$
means that for all $i$ and $j$
$$
C_{ij} = A_{ij} + B_{ij}\;,
$$
where $C_{ij} = \langle v_i|C|v_j\rangle$, $A_{ij}= \langle v_i|A|v_j\rangle$, and $B_{ij}= \langle v_i|B|v_j\rangle$ are all just regular old complex numbers.

Clearly:
$$
C_{ji} = A_{ji} + B_{ji}
$$
and taking the complex conjugate of both sides gives:
$$
C_{ji}^* = A_{ji}^* + B_{ji}^*\;,
$$
which by definition says:
$$
{(C^\dagger)}_{ij} = {(A^\dagger)}_{ij} + {(B^\dagger)}_{ij}\;,
$$
for all $i$ and $j$, so that we have:
$$
C^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger
$$

Comment: Just pedantry: complex conjugation is skew-linear, not linear.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Maybe I am missing something obvious but I can't for my life find what "skew-linear" is supposed to mean. Can you explain further? To me, hft's answer correctly states that complex conjugation is simply linear because this operation is distributive over addition and multiplication.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux skew-linear means you have to take complex conjugation of the coefficients. That is, linear means $L(ax+by)=aLx+bLy$ whereas skew-linear means $S(ax+by)=a^*Sx+b^*Sy$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Oh! Thank you, I am not a native English speaker so I could not relate "semi-linéaire" with skew-linear, though now it seems obvious...

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux the better thing to do is to search it on Google or something. That is the true use of such terminology. The other name for it is anti-linear, and that is such a badly chosen name. They are definitely still somewhat linear, so anti- is just baddddd